# How to create report with tickets closed at certain date in Trac

Tags: sqlite, trac, ticket-system

I wish to create a report that would list all the tickets that were closed in a certain period of time.

The pseudo-code would be like

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
WHERE closed AND date_closed = 'january 2009'
```

The part I am unable to resolve is `date_closed = 'january 2009'`.

Is there a way to do it in Trac?

I am not interested in particular SQL syntax, I can write the time constrictions myself. What I am not certain about is Trac's db structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ticket.* FROM ticket, ticket_change
 WHERE ticket.id = ticket_change.ticket
   AND ticket_change.field = 'status'
   AND ticket_change.newvalue = 'closed'
   AND strftime('%m', ticket_change.time, 'unixepoch') = '01';
```

If you also know the year, instead of strftime you’d better use an expression like vartec’s suggested:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ticket.* FROM ticket, ticket_change
 WHERE ticket.id = ticket_change.ticket
   AND ticket_change.field = 'status'
   AND ticket_change.newvalue = 'closed'
   AND date(ticket_change.time,'unixepoch') 
       BETWEEN date('2009-01-01','start of month') 
           AND date('2009-01-01','start of month','+1 month','-1 day')
```

Comment: It looks like version 0.12 switched to using microseconds in the time fields.  You'll need to use `(ticket_change.time/1000000)` to correctly convert with unixepoch.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM ticket
WHERE status='closed' 
  AND date(changetime,'unixepoch') 
      BETWEEN date('YYYY-MM-DD') /* <- here goes your start date */
          AND date('YYYY-MM-DD') /* <- here goes your end date */
```

If you want a specific month:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket
WHERE status='closed' 
  AND date(changetime,'unixepoch') 
      BETWEEN date('2009-01-01','start of month') 
          AND date('2009-01-01','start of month','+1 month','-1 day')
```

Where `date('2009-01-01','start of month')` is the first day of the month given by date, and `date('2009-01-01','start of month','+1 month','-1 day')` is the last day of the month.

Comment: Last change may be for something else than status.

Comment: Good point kmkaplan. However in my case, I am interested in tickets that are closed at this moment, so "closed" is always the last change. Anyway. Both of yours helped me much. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JS: even in that case you can change the ticket, thus its changetime, when it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Also, regarding the table structure, here you go:

```
CREATE TABLE ticket_change ( 
    ticket   INTEGER,
    time     INTEGER,
    author   TEXT,
    field    TEXT,
    oldvalue TEXT,
    newvalue TEXT,
    UNIQUE ( ticket, time, field ) 
);
```