# Trac query to show tickets that are past due date

Tags: sql, trac

```
SELECT id AS ticket, status, priority, reporter, owner, 
       time AS created, summary
  FROM ticket
  WHERE status IN ('new', 'assigned', 'reopened') and reporter = $USER
  ORDER BY time, priority
```

I am trying to allow reporters to see their past due tickets that they have that are currently open but am new to trac.  Any help using the current date is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does Trac support `NOW()`?

Comment: I don't believe so but I am new to trac so still learning

Comment: Curious what Trac was, I looked it up and found "Trac .... needs a database, ​SQLite, ​PostgreSQL, or ​MySQL." (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall) so the question is, what database is your install using?

Comment: It depends on you custom field definition for *due_date*. You can't get a good answer without knowing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the task you'll need to

- setup a custom ticket field `due_date` or similar (probably done already in your case)
- use a JOIN on Trac db table `ticket_custom` to get that fields values
- retrieve current date (time stamp)
- convert at least one of due_date and current date (probably both) for comparison

I'll skip 1 + 2 here, because there's existing documentation on StackOverflow (i.e. see [How to show due date column in the trac reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120472)) and elsewhere.

Getting to *NOW()*: According to the [authoritative wiki documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports) on reports there is only one dynamically assigned variable for Trac reports: $USER. So you'll need to use an SQL function. I failed to find a portable solution, so these are suggestions depending on your db backend:

- SQLite (Trac default): `current_date` or `datetime('now','localtime')`
- PostgreSQL: `current_timestamp` or `now()`

On the last sub-task: Probably you're not (yet) using true custom time fields, as supported since Trac 1.1.1, because it is a development-snapshot release and still near bleeding-edge. I just point it out for completeness, because it'll save you the hassle of using string conversion workarounds as detailed below.

What you're likely using for now is a string, maybe with improved input method as provided by [DateFieldPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DateFieldPlugin). But a string value is initially useless for direct comparison inside the SQL statement. You'll have to convert all strings to date values or integer to get your report working. See [How to create report with tickets closed at certain date in Trac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585752) as it is related to time stamp conversion. I'd recommend using the native Trac time column format (integer values), that is depending on your Trac version:

- Trac <= 0.11: POSIX seconds
- Trac >= 0.12: POSIX *micro*-seconds

But published examples advocate using a `date` function in the SQL statement (for SQLite). Depending on your date string format this will require string transformation into the appropriate format, i.e. using `substr` like shown in a [sample report for DateFieldPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/attachment/wiki/DateFieldPlugin/Sample_Report.txt).

Putting the pieces together (example for SQLite, assuming `MM/DD/YYYY` as due_date string format):

```
SELECT id AS ticket, status, priority, reporter, owner, 
       time AS created, summary, tc.value as date
  FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN ticket_custom tc on t.id = tc.ticket and tc.name= 'due_date'
  WHERE status IN ('new', 'assigned', 'reopened') and reporter = $USER
       and date(substr(tc.value,7,4)||"-"||substr(tc.value,1,2)||"-"||substr(tc.value,4,2)) < current_date
  ORDER BY time, priority
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself and forgot about this post, but just for completion sake I will post my query.

```
SELECT p.value AS __color__, id AS ticket, status, owner, c1.value AS company,
       time AS created,  c.value AS target_date, summary, p.value as Priority
  FROM ticket t 
  LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority
  LEFT JOIN ticket_custom c ON t.id=c.ticket AND c.name='target_date'
  LEFT JOIN ticket_custom c1 ON t.id=c1.ticket AND c1.name='company'
  WHERE status IN ('new', 'assigned', 'reopened') and reporter= $USER and CURRENT_DATE > target_date
  ORDER BY target_date
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the custom ticket field definition, the format/method you fill your 'target_date' values and the db backend you utilize for you Trac, pleas? As already pointed out in a comment to you question this matters, because it largely depends on that format, if/how you can do the comparison in the SQL statement. Successfully applying your resolution depends on knowing about these facts.